# Why is Voyager 1 approaching Earth?

Tags: solar-system, relative-motion, space-mission

When I read [JPL's mission status for Voyager 1 and Voyager 2](https://voyager.jpl.nasa.gov/mission/status/) the distance between Earth and Voyager 1 is decreasing.

Is it right?

Comment: https://what-if.xkcd.com/38/

Comment: The question is backwards -- it's "why is the Earth approaching Voyager 1"?

Comment: @JohnDvorak https://xkcd.com/1189/

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Voyager $1$ is headed away from the Sun at around $17$ km per second at an angle to the ecliptic of around $35$º.

The orbital velocity of the Earth is $29.8$ km per second, and multiplying by $\cos 35$º to get the component of the velocity in Voyager's direction gives a shade over $24$ km per second.

So at the point in its orbit where Earth is moving closest to the direction of Voyager's travel we are actually catching up with it at around $24 - 17 = 7$ km per second. Conversely at the point in Earth's orbit where it is moving opposite to Voyager it is moving away from us at $24 + 17 = 41$ km per second.

[image: Voyager relative speed]

(not to scale!)

Comment: And here I always thought that the Earth was larger than the Sun, and Voyager was larger than both.  Thanks for clearing things up by pointing out that the diagram is not to scale. ;-)

Comment: I suppose the circle should be more elliptic (projection of an almost-circle to a plane at an angle of 35°)

Comment: I'm 72% certain these diagrams are scaled correctly

Comment: (percentage not to scale)

Comment: I'm sure the earth is blue, not green. That's what they tell us at school, meh.

Comment: At least you got it right by keeping the earth flat.

Comment: is Voyager wearing a physics.stackexchange hat?

Comment: no, that's its dish antenna (which should be pointing at earth)

Comment: I'm slightly surprised it took this long for someone to point out Voyager is apparently beaming its transmissions into outer space :-)